# Tool to Monitor/Tail Log Files given Name pattern/Time of creation

Tags: c#, java, .net, c++, logging

I am generating a bunch of server app loggs via NLog.
Until now I've used LogExpert to monitor them.
The problem now is that I would like to avoid opening each latest timestamped file by hand.

I would like to have some GUI or Windows script/command-line based tool that would allow me to automatically refresh the display showing the latest log in a folder.

Adding to that, if I can configure a file name pattern for each display, that would also be great (*.SERVER1.LOG for display 1, *.SERVER2.LOG for display 2, and so on... )

Any Idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/).